# How to get all the numbers from 2d array that pass the if condition into 1d array

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

sorry for noob question :). I've got 2d array 3x3 filled with random numbers (-5,5)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    dPole[i, j] = nc.Next(-10, 10);
```

I want all the numbers that are positive and then save them into 1d array:

```
foreach (int j in dPole)
            {


                if (j > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(j);
                    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOf1dArray; i++)

                            jPole[i] = j;
                }
            }
```

Output of Console.WriteLine(j)- to check if the condition is right:

```
6
2
5
6
9
8
```

Output of 1d Array:

```
8
8
8
8
8
8
```

Only the last number is saved into array. Why? Thanks.

Comment: Because you're assigning the value to every position of your array? That's what the inner loop does.

Comment: Every time you find a *single* value where `j > 0`, you iterating over the *entire* `jPole` array and assigning that `j` value to every element. It's difficult to work out how to help you here since a) you've abstracted you're problem too much and b) it's not clear why you wrote that loop.

Comment: Note that you can just do `jPole = dPole.Where(x => x > 0).ToArray();` (if you don't need the `WriteLine()`)

Comment: As an additional aside - it helps if you can create a [mcve] and clearly explain what you're doing. E.g. your narrative says the numbers are between `(-5,5)` and then you immediately show us some code that (when we don't know what `nc` is) seems to produce values that (given the later example/code) can exceed 5.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for answer. I don't quite get it though. I know that the inner loop is assigning value to every position of 1d array. What I don't know, is how to assign all the numbers, not just the last one. How would the right code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeOf1dArray; i++)

         jPole[i] = j;
```

because at this loop action last j value is 8 and this loop fills all jPole array with j value every time, that means it fills all with 6 first, than puts 2 at entire array, then 5...... and for last it fills it with 8.

try something like that

```
int i = 0;
foreach (int j in dPole)
        {


            if (j > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(j);
                jPole[i] = j;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative route would be to use `Cast<int>` to flatten the array and use `Where` to filter.

```
int[,] dPole = new int[,] { { 3, -5, 0 }, { -3, 3, 2 }, { -2, 1, 1 } };
int[] jPole = dPole.Cast<int>().Where(i => i > 0).ToArray();
// jPole is now { 3, 3, 2, 1, 1 };
```